# LXC control script launched via crontab doesn't work properly, but when used from cmd line is OK

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, lxc

I have a script that uses named pipes to control containers. The script monitors the named pipe for commands and executes whatever is fed into its input. Script must run as the user that owns the containers. Any other user can send commands to the script.

Script works when executed on the command line. But i want it to be a daemon and start itself on system boot. Tried setting it up as a service with set user - not working. Tried it as a cron job - `@restart /home/conts/cont-control.sh` - that also doesn't work. The named pipe is created, the `shutdown` part works ok, but the others - don't.

Can someone suggest where may be the problem?

Here's the actual script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=/tmp/container-control
mkfifo $input
chmod o+w $input

trap "rm $input" EXIT

stopAllContainers () {
    for i in $(lxc-ls); do
        lxc-stop -n $i
    done
}

startContainerGroup () {
    lxc-autostart -g $1
}

startContainer () {
    lxc-start -n $1
}

stopContainer () {
    lxc-stop -n $1
}

while true; do if read -r -a cmd <$input; then
    case ${cmd[0]} in
        "shutdown")
            stopAllContainers
            echo "Shutting down containers ... done" > $input
        ;;
        "start-group")
            startContainerGroup ${cmd[1]}
            echo "Starting group ${cmd[1]} ... done" > $input
        ;;
        "start")
            startContainer ${cmd[1]}
            echo "Starting ${cmd[1]} container ... done" > $input
        ;;
        "stop")
            stopContainer ${cmd[1]}
            echo "Stopping ${cmd[1]} container ... done" > $input
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Unsupported command: ${cmd[0]} with argument: ${cmd[1]} ... fail" > $input
        ;;
    esac
fi
done
```

EDIT: After editing the crontab so that it outputs errors to a file, it seems that the problem is lxc related. Here's the output when trying to start a container named mysql-dev:

```
lxc-start: mysql-dev: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state
lxc-start: mysql-dev: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start
lxc-start: mysql-dev: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
lxc-start: mysql-dev: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options
```

Again, the shutdown command works ok - the others don't. When run from cmd line, the script behaves normally.

Comment: Where are the `lxc-` commands located? What is the output of `type lxc-ls`?

Comment: @terdon `lxc-ls is /usr/bin/lxc-ls`, `lxc-start is /usr/bin/lxc-start`, `lxc-autostart is /usr/bin/lxc-autostart`

Comment: Hmm, those should actually be in cron's PATH. Ok, you need to get some debugging info. First, change the crontab line to `@restart /home/conts/cont-control.sh 2>/tmp/cronLog`. That will print any error messages to `/tmp/cronLog`. Reboot the machine to get the script to run and then tell us what errors you get. Also, although `/usr/bin` is in cron's PATH, the behavior you describe strongly suggests it just doesn't find the relevant commands. So, just in case, also try using the full path to each command: `/usr/bin/lxc-ls` instead of `lxc-ls`, `/usr/bin/lxc-start` instead of `lxc-start` etc.

Comment: @terdon edited the OP. It definitely finds the commands, the problem seems to be lxc related.

Comment: Odd. What user's crontab are you using? Did you just run `crontab -e` or are you using a system-wide crontab? Did you try the `--logfile` option as suggested by the error message? Is there anything useful there?

Comment: yes, `crontab -e` from the specific user that owns the containers. For now will just workaround it via ssh. Added "answer" below.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you want to do is start the containers daemonized.

```
-d, --daemon
Run the container as a daemon. As the container has no more tty, if an error 
occurs nothing will be displayed, the log file can be used to check the error. 
(This is the default mode)
```

So in your example something like this:

```
startContainer () {
    lxc-start -d -n $1
}
```

The failure messages, I suspect, are occurring because when you run this as a stop/start script there's no TTY available for lxc* to connect to your containers and so they're failing to start.

#### References

- [lxc-start man page](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man1/lxc-start.1.html)

Comment: no, didn't help either. And the `lxc-autostart` doesn't have the `-d` option and it fails as well. I mean... it's erratic behavior. `lxc-stop` runs just fine as is, the others don't....... Added answer - i will just work around it with good ole ssh.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out the suggestions, i conclude that it's probably some kind of a bug or an esoteric config peculiarity on my system (`Linux main 4.18.0-17-generic #18~18.04.1-Ubuntu`). Anyway, hunting it down is probably not worth it.

In case someone experiences something similar, perhaps they should settle for a workaround. This is what i ultimately did:

- rework the script so that it's usable without the named pipes
- simply invoke it via ssh command on localhost like: `ssh conts@ubuntu 'cont-control.sh shutdown'`.

With a certificate in authorized_keys it has 0 overhead.

Thank you all.